# Why Json is null in this situation?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to return a JSON encoded array from a PHP page via ajax.
here's my code from the calling page

---

```
$('#test_load').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'/actions/admin_load.php',      
            dataType: 'json',
            asynch:false,
            data:"action=4",
            success: function(json) {
                alert("we're back");
                alert(json.a);
            }
        });
    });
```

---

here's my php code

```
//return json array
    case "4" :
        $str2 =  "HELLO";
        $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
            $str = json_encode($arr);
        echo $str;

    break;
```

---

I keep getting "json is null".
Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: By the way, you mean `async`, not `asynch`.

Comment: Are you sure that it is making it into case "4"?

Comment: Does `data: {action: 4}` work, instead of `data: "action=4"`?

Comment: Have you tried using firebug or something similar to look at exactly what the response is from your POST?

Comment: have you tried using firebug to make sure the ajax request returns valid json as you believe it does?

Comment: @malonso haha 5 seconds apart! woo!

Comment: @Relequestual - Haha, great minds think alike :)

Comment: I copied all your code and tried it, and it worked fine exactly as you had it, even with the misspelled "asynch" and the call to json_encode as you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try "catch" the variable

$action=$_POST['action'];
then us it in switch
 case "$action" : ....